# Mysql query and sorting for couple columns

Tags: php, mysql

here is my query and what I am trying to do is to select best match case based on those three entries and sort them so that best matched cases are the first to show up. It does not work, it shows everything that happen to satisfy those OR conditions. And it does not sort out by best match. So is there a better way to write query with this idea?

```
$displayLeads = $DB->query("SELECT * FROM autoleads WHERE `lead_status`='NEW' AND `contact_email` IS NOT NULL AND (`status_date` = '".$date_sort."' OR `contact_address` LIKE '%".$state_sort."%' OR`status_code` = '".$code_sort."') ORDER BY status_code = $code_sort DESC, status_date = $date_sort DESC");
```

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: It does not work, it shows everything that happen to satisfy those OR conditions. And it does not sort out by best match.

Comment: Please define "best match" and edit your question with sample data and desired results.

Comment: here is the example, some one enter date: 2015-01-08, status: 218 and state: MI. What I want is to display everything that matches those entries. But if one condition was not met or was not entered I want it to display the rest of them.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming that by "best" match you mean the most matches to the subquery, then you can count the matches and order by that:

```
SELECT *
FROM autoleads
WHERE `lead_status`='NEW' AND `contact_email` IS NOT NULL AND
      (`status_date` = '".$date_sort."' OR
       `contact_address` LIKE '%".$state_sort."%' OR
       `status_code` = '".$code_sort."'
      )
ORDER BY (`status_date` = '".$date_sort."' +
          `contact_address` LIKE '%".$state_sort."%' +
          `status_code` = '".$code_sort."'
         ) DESC
```

This assumes that none of the columns take on `NULL` values.  If they can, then just replace the column name with `coalesce(col, '')`.

Comment: I didn't get what if there as nothing entered for one of the fields? Cause I want it to work even if only one of those conditions was entered

Comment: I don't understand your comment.  Your question says nothing about the content of the variables.  You question is about ordering.